# How to push/pull data from Wso2 DAS from another application

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I am new to WSO2 DAS. I am analyzing WSO2 DAS for our new product.
I have a confusion. Does the WSO2 DAS support push or pull data?

I have created sample soap event receiver in WSO2 DAS with event sream that has simple type data.

The event receiver creation page says that http://localhost:9763/services//receive will be used to receive the data, but I do not see anything when i type this url for my receiver url.

Since I do not see any wsdl how do i push the data from my application to this wso2 receiver.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Regards
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

Service will be created for the receiver name you specify and the **receive** will be the default endpoint

```
http://localhost:9763/services/<event_receiver_name>/receive
```

If your soap receiver name is **test** receiver. You can push data to following endpoint

```
http://localhost:9763/services/test/receive
```

You can access wsdl by using folllowing URL

```
http://localhost:9763/services/test/receive?wsdl
```